# Creating a tag with the Bitbucket Server API fails

Tags: curl, bitbucket

I'm trying to use the Bitbucket Server RST API to create a new tag for a specific commit (represented by a hash). Please note that I use basic auth but don't write it to my examples below. What I've got is an HTTP 500 response.

```
curl -XPOST 'http://<server>/rest/api/latest/projects/p1/repos/r1/tags' -d '{
    "name": "my-new-tag",
    "hash": "0d2019c8e18f8c961cdb67cb27afb69b04f3a10b"
}'
```

I also tried:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://<server>/2.0/repositories/username/r1/refs/tags' -d '{
    "name": "my-new-tag",
    "hash": "0d2019c8e18f8c961cdb67cb27afb69b04f3a10b"
}'
```

But in this case the request ends up in an HTTP 404 and I think that's because this is not a Bitbucket Server URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
curl -X POST -k -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -s -u <Your Account>:<Your password> -i 'https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/username/r1/refs/tags' --data '{
       "name": "my-new-tag",
       "target":{
           "hash": "0d2019c8e18f8c961cdb67cb27afb69b04f3a10b"
       }
    }'
```

or

```
curl -X POST -k -H 'Content-Type: application/json' Authorization: Basic <<Authentication String>>' -i 'https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/username/r1/refs/tags' --data '{
       "name": "my-new-tag",
       "target":{
           "hash": "0d2019c8e18f8c961cdb67cb27afb69b04f3a10b"
       }
    }'
```